# foreach loop does not return all array results

Tags: php, arrays

I have the below code but I'm not getting all the results from the array

```
  foreach ($reviewers as $login_name => $common_name) {
    $allowed_values = [
      '' => 'All',
      $login_name => $common_name,
    ];
  }
```

Comment: You are overwriting the array on each loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overwrite the entire array each time through the loop.  Just add the key and value in the loop:

```
  $allowed_values = ['' => 'All'];

  foreach ($reviewers as $login_name => $common_name) {
      $allowed_values[$login_name] = $common_name;
  }
```